# lines break of 3 textView items according to their length

Tags: android, layout, android-linearlayout, android-constraintlayout, onmeasure

Problem have this UI problem:

1) I have 3 `textViews` which I want to hold in one parent view.

2) I want to populate as many items as possible in as few lines as possible.

3) Only between 2 items there is a separator.

Suggested algorithm:

Get the container's widthGet each item unspecified width (For that I have to create a custom textView to override `onMeasure()`).

Calculate and keep aside `"last line remaining width"`.

If next textView can fit in the last line remaining width:

- make the last separator visible
- put it in the same line and move to next textView item

else:

- open a new line with `remaining width = (container's width - current
  item's width)`
- make the last separator invisible
- put the current item in that line (break lines if needed)

I have two options:

1. To use a vertical linear layout of horizontal linear layouts.
2. To use a constraint layout.

I would fill a List of Lists and will populate the horizontal linear layouts via code.

Or fill the constraint layout via code (less generic and I guess more difficult).

Is there any simpler solution?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding your requirements correctly, I believe [the FlexboxLayout library from Google](https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout) should do exactly what you want.

You'd probably use a `FlexboxLayout` (rather than a `RecyclerView` with a `FlexboxLayoutManager`), but it is good to note that this library also supports recycling.

Comment: Thanks, i will take a look. What's the advantage over using android's constraint layout?

Comment: You just put all your views in it and it will wrap them to new lines for you